# How can select only two audio streams in a video and feed it to the ebur128 filter wiithin ffmpeg?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I want to use FFmpeg to analyze the loudness of an MXF video file.
I have an MXF file with 8 mono audio streams. I only want to feed the first two streams through the ebur128 filter. But I can't find a way to do that. The FFmpeg documentation is not clear to me, as I am fairly new to FFmpeg.

I tried several things:

```
ffmpeg -i source.mxf -nostats -filter_complex ebur128=dualmono=true:panlaw=-3.01dB -f null -
```

I am sure it's just that I don't have the filtering syntax right. But hey... I'm a newbie...

---

```
ffmpeg -i myVideo.mxf -nostats -filter_complex [0:a:0][0:a:1]amerge; ebur128=dualmono=true:panlaw=-3.01 -f null -
```

And this is the resulting console output:

```
ffmpeg version 2.8.6 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
built with llvm-gcc 4.2.1 (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
configuration: --prefix=/Volumes/Ramdisk/sw --enable-gpl --enable-        pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-libspeex --enable-libvpx --disable-decoder=libvpx --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-avfilter --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-filters --enable-libgsm --enable-libvidstab --enable-libx265 --disable-doc --arch=x86_64 --enable-runtime-cpudetect
libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100

Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.1 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.2 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.3 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.4 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.5 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.6 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.7 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.8 : mono
Input #0, mxf, from 'myVideo.mxf':
Metadata:
uid             : a727a381-1f5a-11e7-bdc8-18af61b92a5a
generation_uid  : a727a382-1f5a-11e7-9a04-18af61b92a5a
company_name    : Adobe Systems Incorporated
product_name    : Adobe Media Encoder
product_version : 11.0.2
application_platform: Mac OS X
product_uid     : 0c3919fe-46e8-11e5-a151-feff819cdc9f
modification_date: 2017-04-12 08:33:07
material_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010D1113000000A0C9D501557805A5DF7018AF61B92A5A
timecode        : 00:00:00:00
Duration: 00:05:24.08, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 59986 kb/s
Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg2video (4:2:2), yuv422p(tv, unknown/bt709/bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 50000 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 50 tbc
Metadata:
  file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010D12133A5D15A0C9D501557805A5B09318AF61B92A5A
  file_package_name: Source Package
Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, 1 channels, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
Metadata:
  file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010D12133A5D15A0C9D501557805A5B09318AF61B92A5A
  file_package_name: Source Package
Stream #0:2: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, 1 channels, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
Metadata:
  file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010D12133A5D15A0C9D501557805A5B09318AF61B92A5A
  file_package_name: Source Package
Stream #0:3: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, 1 channels, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
Metadata:
  file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010D12133A5D15A0C9D501557805A5B09318AF61B92A5A
  file_package_name: Source Package
Stream #0:4: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, 1 channels, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
Metadata:
  file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010D12133A5D15A0C9D501557805A5B09318AF61B92A5A
  file_package_name: Source Package
Stream #0:5: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, 1 channels, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
Metadata:
  file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010D12133A5D15A0C9D501557805A5B09318AF61B92A5A
  file_package_name: Source Package
Stream #0:6: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, 1 channels, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
Metadata:
  file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010D12133A5D15A0C9D501557805A5B09318AF61B92A5A
  file_package_name: Source Package
Stream #0:7: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, 1 channels, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
Metadata:
  file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010D12133A5D15A0C9D501557805A5B09318AF61B92A5A
  file_package_name: Source Package
Stream #0:8: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, 1 channels, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
Metadata:
  file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010D12133A5D15A0C9D501557805A5B09318AF61B92A5A
  file_package_name: Source Package
Filter amerge has a unconnected output

bash: -f: command not found
```

I changed the name of the video to myVideo.mxf.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want a stereo output from two mono inputs:

```
ffmpeg -i input -filter_complex "[0:a:0][0:a:1]amerge,ebur128" -f null -
```

Comment: Yeah, but I also want to add some arguments. And I guess that's where the errors occur

Comment: Like dualmono=true. And setting the panlaw

Comment: Now I get an error:
    Error initializing filter 'ebur128' with args 'dualmono=true:panlaw=-3.01dB'

Comment: @Edwin That's not the whole error, but I'll have to guess that you need to change  `panlaw=-3.01dB` to `panlaw=-3.01`. Also, multi-channel input files are not affected by `dualmono` (as stated in the [docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#ebur128-1)), and `panlaw` is for "dual mono" which yours is not.

Comment: After the amerge, the input is no longer mono, but multi-channel. Remove those two options.

Comment: Filter amerge has a unconnected output
bash: -f: command not found

Yeah, I am still new here... *sigh*

Comment: @Edwin I'll need to see your exact command and the resulting complete console output from the command. I had to guess the content of your input because you didn't provide any info. You can edit your question to add this info.

Comment: I changed the initial question. I added the console messages and the commands I used to get that message.

Comment: There should be a comma and no space after the amerge.

Comment: Thanks! It kind of does something. But is this a valid syntaxis? Because it says "Error initializing complex filters. Option not found" ffmpeg -i myVideo.mxf -nostats -filter_complex [0:a:0][0:a:1]amerge,ebur128=dualmono=true:panlaw=-3.01 -f null -

Comment: @Edwin Again, you'll need to update your question with your command and the resulting complete console output. Also, 2.8.6 is old. [Get a new one](http://www.evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/).

Answer (score 0):

I use "join" instead of "amerge" to get a stereo from two separate streams

**For Stereo :**

```
ffmpeg -i input -filter_complex '[0:1][0:2]join=inputs=2:channel_layout=stereo[audio]; [audio]ebur128=peak=true' -f null -
```

and I get this type of result :

```
Integrated loudness:
    I:         -22.9 LUFS
    Threshold: -33.1 LUFS

  Loudness range:
    LRA:         1.4 LU
    Threshold: -42.8 LUFS
    LRA low:   -23.4 LUFS
    LRA high:  -22.0 LUFS

  True peak:
    Peak:       -8.4 dBFS
```

**For 5.1 :**

```
ffmpeg -i input -filter_complex '[0:1][0:2][0:3][0:4][0:5][0:6]join=inputs=6:channel_layout=5.1[audio]; [audio]ebur128=peak=true' -f null -
```